# Refactor jQuery to minimize delay

Tags: jquery, refactoring

So I have a mountain of mouseenter and mouseleave requests, and I was wondering if there was a way to refactor it.

jQuery code

```
// product features
  // highly interactive
  $('.highly-interactive').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.highly-interactive-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.highly-interactive').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.highly-interactive-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // operating system
  $('.operating-system').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.operating-system-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.operating-system').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.operating-system-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // batteries
  $('.batteries').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.batteries-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.batteries').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.batteries-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // hypoallergenic
  $('.hypoallergenic').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.hypoallergenic-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.hypoallergenic').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.hypoallergenic-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // compatible tablet sizes
  $('.compTablet').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.compTablet-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.compTablet').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.compTablet-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // genuine personality
  $('.genuine-personality').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.genuine-personality-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.genuine-personality').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.genuine-personality-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // size
  $('.size').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.size-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.size').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.size-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // soft and safe
  $('.soft-and-safe').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.soft-and-safe-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.soft-and-safe').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.soft-and-safe-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });

  // expanding app
  $('.expanding-app').mouseenter( function() {
    $('.expanding-app-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
  });

  $('.expanding-app').mouseleave( function() {
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.expanding-app-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
  });
```

Currently, there is a delay when hiding `.main-image` the image that is supposed to show is showing behind it even though `display: none;` is being set on the `.main-image`

So the code seems to be doing what it should there's just a delay in the `main-image` being hidden which is happening to all of the above queries.

Update

HTML

```
<img src="./images/product-features-default.png" alt="plush" class="main-image">

<section class="images">
  <img src="./images/HIImage.png" alt="Highly interactive" class="highly-interactive-image">
  <img src="./images/tablet-sizesImage.png" alt="Tablet Sizes" class="operating-system-image">
  <img src="./images/batteryImage.png" alt="Batteries Images" class="batteries-image">
  <img src="./images/Hypoallergenic.png" alt="Hypoallergenic" class="hypoallergenic-image">
  <img src="./images/Octobo-Tablet.png" alt="Compatible Tablet Sizes" class="compTablet-image">
  <img src="./images/GenuinePersonality.png" alt="Genuine Personality" class="genuine-personality-image">
  <img src="./images/sizeImage.png" alt="Size" class="size-image">
  <img src="./images/soft&safe.png" alt="Soft & Safe" class="soft-and-safe-image">
  <img src="./images/Expanding.png" alt="Expanding App" class="expanding-app-image">
</section>

<!-- highly interactive -->
<section class="highly-interactive feature">
  <section class="text">
    <h2>Highly Interactive</h2>

    <section class="hover">
      <img src="./images/HIIcon.svg" class="icon">
      <span>8 separate sensor arrays invisibly integrated into Octobo’s arms and body, responsive LED lighting, and the touchscreen itself</span>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>

<!-- operating system -->
<section class="operating-system feature">
  <section class="text">
    <h2>Operating System</h2>

    <section class="hover">
      <img src="./images/tablet-sizes.svg" class="icon">
      <span>iOS 6.0, Android, 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich and up</span>
      <img src="./images/operating-system.png" alt="Android and Apple logos" class="OS-logos">
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

This is only two section, but there is an image for every section and every section is laid out the same.

Comment: Why all the JavaScript? Add a common class to every product feature (e.g. `.feature`) and use CSS: `.feature .hover { display: none } .feature h2 { color: #1a2d45 } .feature:hover .hover { display: block } .feature:hover h2 { color: #15d4ef }`; If you then can make the `...-image` element also a child of the feature or a common element like `.main-image` you can do all with pure CSS.

Comment: How would I handle the hiding of the main image and showing of the relevant image @Andreas all images are in a separate class https://i.gyazo.com/96bb7e2d882c2598a61b02f8412d582d.png

Comment: This you would then have to do with JavaScript but with way less code (may need some tweaking on the `className` part to get the correct class): `$(".feature").on("mouseenter", function() { $(this.className.replace(/\s*feature\s*/g,"") + "-image").show(); $(".main-image").hide(); }).on("mouseleave", function() { $(this.className.replace(/\s*feature\s*/g,"")) + "-image").hide(); $(".main-image").show(); });`

Comment: This would be a proper candidate for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com (but have a look at the help _before_ posting)

Comment: There seems to be an error in your solution @Andreas https://i.gyazo.com/721557a9f393d0c195ff75e6fe45c348.png as far as I can tell everything is closed. Thanks for the `codereview` link

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Then it would be possible to create a demo of the CSS / jquery

Comment: Ok see update @OliverTrampleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a custom attribute to the feature sections then you can greatly simplify your code.

I have added `feature="highly-interactive"` (or the equivalent) to each of the feature sections. The code then pulls this attribute out one `mousenter` or `mouseleave`. With you consistent naming structure you can then append `-image` to show/hide the correct feature image.

The highlighting of the heading can be done in CSS.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add event for mouse entering a feature
$( ".feature" ).mouseenter(function() {
    
    // Get feature name, append '-image' and show
    $("." + $(this).attr("feature") + "-image").show();
    
    // Hide the main image
    $('.main-image').hide();
    
});


// Add event for mouse leaving a feature
$( ".feature" ).mouseleave(function() {
    
    // Get feature name, append '-image' and hide
    $("." + $(this).attr("feature") + "-image").hide();
    
    // Show the main image
    $('.main-image').show();
    

});
```

```css
.feature:hover h2 {
  color: #15d4ef;
}

.images img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="./images/product-features-default.png" alt="plush" class="main-image">

<section class="images">
  <img src="./images/HIImage.png" alt="Highly interactive" class="highly-interactive-image">
  <img src="./images/tablet-sizesImage.png" alt="Tablet Sizes" class="operating-system-image">
  <img src="./images/batteryImage.png" alt="Batteries Images" class="batteries-image">
  <img src="./images/Hypoallergenic.png" alt="Hypoallergenic" class="hypoallergenic-image">
  <img src="./images/Octobo-Tablet.png" alt="Compatible Tablet Sizes" class="compTablet-image">
  <img src="./images/GenuinePersonality.png" alt="Genuine Personality" class="genuine-personality-image">
  <img src="./images/sizeImage.png" alt="Size" class="size-image">
  <img src="./images/soft&safe.png" alt="Soft & Safe" class="soft-and-safe-image">
  <img src="./images/Expanding.png" alt="Expanding App" class="expanding-app-image">
</section>

<!-- highly interactive -->
<section feature="highly-interactive" class="highly-interactive feature">
  <section class="text">
    <h2>Highly Interactive</h2>

    <section class="hover">
      <img src="./images/HIIcon.svg" class="icon">
      <span>8 separate sensor arrays invisibly integrated into Octobo’s arms and body, responsive LED lighting, and the touchscreen itself</span>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>

<!-- operating system -->
<section feature="operating-system" class="operating-system feature">
  <section class="text">
    <h2>Operating System</h2>

    <section class="hover">
      <img src="./images/tablet-sizes.svg" class="icon">
      <span>iOS 6.0, Android, 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich and up</span>
      <img src="./images/operating-system.png" alt="Android and Apple logos" class="OS-logos">
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Hm doesn't seem to be showing the relevant image when hovering. the main image is hiding, but the img in the image's class doesn't show.

Comment: You need to add `feature="operating-system" ` to each of your wrapper sections (replace the name as appropriate - see just under the line `<!-- operating system -->
`). You could do a search on the `class` but this would mean you couldn't add any other classes. This approach is more versatile.

Comment: No problem, glad we could help

Comment: Instead of adding an invalid attribute use the class which is already there. Split the `className` and grab the non-`feature` one (or use `.classlist`).

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize your code at best way below. As hover in & out is as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

You can further minimize it, but for that you need to share your html structure, so we can make a generalized script for all the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

```
$('.highly-interactive').hover(function(){
    $('.highly-interactive-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.highly-interactive-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});

$('.operating-system').hover(function(){
    $('.operating-system-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.operating-system-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});

$('.batteries').hover(function(){
    $('.batteries-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.batteries-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});

$('.hypoallergenic').hover(function(){
    $('.hypoallergenic-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.hypoallergenic-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();


$('.compTablet').hover(function(){
    $('.compTablet-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.compTablet-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});


$('.genuine-personality').hover(function(){
    $('.genuine-personality-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.genuine-personality-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});


$('.size').hover(function(){
    $('.size-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.size-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});

$('.soft-and-safe').hover(function(){
    $('.soft-and-safe-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.soft-and-safe-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});

$('.expanding-app').hover(function(){
    $('.expanding-app-image').show();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#15d4ef');
    $('.main-image').hide();
    $('.hover', this).show();
},function(){
    $('.hover', this).hide();
    $('h2', this).css('color', '#1A2D45');
    $('.expanding-app-image').hide();
    $('.main-image').show();
});
```